# Masking super class functionality while extending it

Tags: java, inheritance, architecture

Does it make sense for class "B" to extend "A", and mask some of its functionalities ? for example by putting the following code at top of the the functions that we want to mask in A:

```
if subclass type is B
  don't execute the function
else 
  execute the function
```

Does this contradict the general idea of inheritance in Software Design ?

Comment: You need to mention the programming language you are using.

Comment: This is a general question regarding Software Design in general, but I will mention Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @rilent mentioned technically it is possible that you just override base methods with empty implementation. But that is a bad design IMO. Even @rilent agrees to this I believe.

If child is not supposed to support particular behavior (say method), then such behavior can/should not be abstracted using parent/super/base class (whatever). Such abstraction will always result in empty methods in child classes or at the most they will throw not implemented exceptions (this is even worse).

See example below and you will get idea what I am trying to explain.

```
Bird {
    Mate();
    Fly();
    Swim();
}

Eagle : Bird {
    Mate() { /* :) */ }
    Fly() { /* Oh come on, of course I can. */ }
    Swim() { /* Oops, sorry I can't. */ }
}

Penguin : Bird {
    Mate() { /* :) */ }
    Fly() { /* Sorry I'm a flightless bird. */ }
    Swim() { /* Yeah, I can do this well. */ }
}
```

Now you see why I said it's a bad design. Just doesn't make sense, right? So what can we do?

**Interfaces**

You can abstract specific behavior using interface instead of inheritance. I would reconsider above classes and have something of this sort. `Fly()` and `Swim()` are defined by `ICanFly` and `ICanSwim` respectively.

```
Bird {
    Mate();
}

Eagle : Bird, ICanFly {
    Mate() { }
    Fly() { }
}

Penguin : Bird, ICanSwim {
    Mate() { }
    Swim() { }
}
```

[8 birds that can't fly](https://www.britannica.com/list/8-birds-that-cant-fly).

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be a design mistake to do something like that. Not saying it wouldnt work, if you have B who extends A and you don't want B to execute some of A functions, just override them and let them empty.

```
class A {
function myFunction() { do some stuffs and forbidden to be executed by B}
}
class B extends A {
@Override
function myFunction() {}
}
```

But i still assume It's not something very clean to do.
I would always go this way : If you need some functions that can't be executed by B, just create a subclass C that extends A and let A the cleanest possible.